# how can i dynamically click on table row for every table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm new on automation using Selenium with Java. Actually I'm testing a scenario that is base on Student form testing. Now issue I have faced a lot and try to resolve but aloss I'm fail I want to send dynamically firstname and last name in input field and then filter the data against firstname and last name but now I want to click on dynamically filter data meanwhile want to click a element on row please help me to figure out this problem

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("");
driver.findElement(By.id("login_username")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.id("login_password")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/button[1]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lsmainmenu']/li[2]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lsmainmenu']/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement x=driver.findElement(By.id("personListFilterForm_name"));
x.sendKeys("Bern_name Fuss_name");

Thread.sleep(200);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='student-list-filters']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/input")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.id("i wan this section is click dynmacilly according to firsname and lastename ")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to click on the given firstname\lastname. Assuming that you already know firstname\ lastname

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\*[contains(text(),'Firstname')]")).click();
```